# Difference between user groupId and scopeGroupId

Tags: liferay, usergroups

Whats the difference between `themeDisplay.getUser().getGroupId()` and `themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()`?

If I retrieve `Layouts` (pages) from it, would they have any different URL pattern like, `/web-or-user/<user>/*` or `/web-or-user-or-group/<group>/*`?

I mean am I right to say that every user has his own group or something?

As I understand it so far, it seems like User *Foo* has group *UserFoo* and group *GroupFoo* so you can retrieve pages personal to *Foo* or group of Foo ... Am I in the good way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every authenticated user can have their own private and public pages which would be the getUser().getGroupId().

Then there is also the Community that a user is currently viewing which is the Scope Group ID.

So yes you're right! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a group Id you can get the public or private pages of the user. while a scopeGroupId is related to the permission of your portlet(refer chapter security and permission in (http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4)